# Error while executing Neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have executed following query to load CSV file and store into Neo4j graph. I framed the query using APOC stored procedures in Neo4j. But, it is showing an error. The query is as:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv("file:///Product_CSV.csv",{sep:","}) YIELD al
CALL apoc.create.node(['Product'], ProductTitle:al.Product_Title,ProductType:al.Product_type}) YIELD node
RETURN count(*);
```

The error is:

> Unknown procedure output: `al` (line 1, column 71 (offset: 70)) "CALL
>   apoc.load.csv("file:///Product_CSV.csv",{sep:","}) YIELD al CALL
>   poc.create.node(['Product'],
>   ProductTitle:al.Product_Title,ProductType:al.Product_type}) YIELD node
>   RETURN count(*);"

Anybody can help me out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in the `apoc.load.csv` procedure signature:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('url',{sep:";"}) YIELD lineNo, list, map
```

This procedure does not produces an `al` output as specified in your query.

Change your query to:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv("file:///Product_CSV.csv",{sep:","}) YIELD map
CALL apoc.create.node(['Product'],{ProductTitle:map.Product_Title,ProductType:map.Product_type}) YIELD node
RETURN count(*);
```

Comment: Thank you, @Bruno Peres. Can I have your guidance on "How to use apoc.load.csv in conjunction with apoc.merge.node and apoc.merge.relationship " which creates nodes of two types and create relationship between them using APOC stored procedures. Cheers!

Comment: @SaiSriKrishnaKotha You are welcome! Sure, can you ask a new question about it? Its better than use the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Thank You for the response @Bruno Peres